# chrome javascript save data for access through filesystem

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-chrome, local-storage

I need to save some key/value pairs continuously and using a javascript on a web page. Currently, I am saving those pairs in HTML5 local storage using

```
localStorage.setItem("key_1", val_1);
```

I need to access those values in realtime in python or R, for that I am using sqlite to read the localstorage db file in

`/Users/user_name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/<site_identifier>.localstorage`

But the issue is that Chrome doesn't update the local storage file in real-time there is usually a 10-second delay and sometimes more. However, if I see in application tab in developer tools it updates the key/value pair in real-time.

Please advise how can I save the values and get them in python in near real-time, Am I taking the wrong path here to achieve the results, Any alternative method to access data from javascript running in a Chrome session to Python would be fine as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using chrome to provide a front-end to your python/R code?

Comment: No, I just want to get some values from a javascript running on a website and perform some real-time analysis on it.

Comment: Could you use python as the webserver and have javascript make calls to the python webserver via ajax? The python webserver could save to its own sqlite db instead of the chrome one.

Comment: No, that would not be possible as well. I am running a javascript on a website and trying to scrape and analyse some real-time information it provides.

Comment: I tried the selenium path but already, But wanted it to be a bit more easy to setup so took this path.

Comment: It's a website you do not have control of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148936/discussion-between-anonr-and-nick).